# Blazor WebAssembly route messes up NavLink

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a pure WebAssembly Blazor app with two pages, PageA and PageB.

In PageA I have a link `<a href="PageB/Item1">Go to Item1</a>`

In PageB I have this:

```
@page "/PageB"
@page "/PageB/{itemname}"
```

Clicking on the link redirects me to `http://localhost/MySite/PageB/Item1` just fine.
Now when I click on my navbar, to go back to PageA the whole app reloads or has a wrong routing.

1.) Whole app reloads when I have this in my NavLink:
`<NavLink href="/PageA">PageA</NavLink>`

2.) The URL is wrong (**/PageB/PageA**) when omitting the `/`:
`<NavLink href="PageA">PageA</NavLink>`

I really don't know why the whole app reloads when clicking a NavLink. It only happens when my URL contains a Route Parameter. Just clicking the NavLink navigates tottaly normal. And in the other case **it's like /PageB has become my new root for the NavMenu**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add slash on front of each route like:

```
@page "/PageB"
@page "/PageA"
```

Then go into your _Host.cshtml if your app in Server side or index.html if the app is WASM and add or modify of exists the base href like;

```
<base href="/mysite/">
```

Comment: It works, didn't work at first, but base was missing (code didn't recompile at first). Thanks :)